# ZXingObjC iOS archive issue: 'ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h' file not found Edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I followed the instructions in the readme file and it worked fine when I ran it as debug config on simulator or device, but when I archived I got this error:

> 'ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h' file not found

I tried to set header search path in build settings as something like `./libs/ZXingObjC-8f83c0b` and then got the error

> libs/ZXingObjC-8f83c0b/ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h:20:9: 'ZXingObjC/ZXAztecDecoder.h' file not found

any idea how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Have you tried copying the ZXing library into your project?

Comment: If it's happening when you archive, then it sounds like the search paths are set differently for Debug and Release.

Comment: I dragged the xcode project into my project like the readme says. before I ran into the archive issue, no value was set for header search path for any configuration at all.

Comment: BTW, I got the same error with the demo app BarcodeScanner when archiving: /Users/ross/iphone_old_work/KitchenAid/doc/TheLevelUp-ZXingObjC-8f83c0b/examples/BarcodeScanner/BarcodeScanner-Prefix.pch:14:11: 'ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h' file not found

Comment: I can't think of a reason to archive the header with the build. Try unchecking it from the relevant target.

Answer (score 1):

add in Header Search Paths

$(SRCROOT)/../..

recursive

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
- add "$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts" to header search path
- go to ZXingObjC project's build settings, change public header folder path from $(PROJECT_NAME)Headers to $(PROJECT_NAME)